# Contour plots in python with time on X-Axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, contourf

I wish to do a contour plot in python with the sample data given below:-
X-Axis(Time)   Y-Axis(D) Z-Axis(C)
15:18:48         10        26
15:18:49         11        28
15:18:50         13        30
.                .         .
.                .         .
Given below is my code

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
load_var=pd.read_excel(r'path\file.xlsx')
x=pd.DataFrame(load_var['Time'])
y=pd.DataFrame(load_var['D'])
z=pd.DataFrame(load_var['C'])
plt.contour(x,y,z)
```

Error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
Kindly clear the following doubts:
1] How to create the mesh-grid using X-axis as time and Y-axis as values mentioned under 'D' ?
2] Please Suggest the updations in the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) states, the 'Z' parameter of `plt.contour` should be with size of `(M, N)`: if x, y have 500 values, the size of z should be (500, 2).

You supply `z` which is a single column, aka (500, 1). That is not how the contours plot works.

P.S - no need in `pd.DataFrame(load_var['C'])`, you can directly work with `load_var['C']`.
Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.2, 0.1, 0.5], 'y': [34.2, 73.1, 43.5], 'z':[105, 108, 101], 'z2':[105, 108, 101], 'z3':[105, 108, 101]})
plt.contour(df.x,df.y, df[['z', 'z2', 'z3']])
plt.show()
```

output:
[image: contour example]

Comment: I will try out this suggested way and revert you.

Comment: Could you also please address the issue of having time on the x-Axis  as mentioned in the  data above ?